# Websites not opening

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-connection

Okay, the problem isn't that simple as it says in the title. I have dual booted manjaro with windows 10 and have hypervisor in windows.

90% of the time, most common site's (such as Google and all it's subdomains) along with few other sites won't open on manjaro and windows both, but I can ping them and they even open from within the hypervisor, but not from host machine. And 10% of the times it opens.

Firefox in manjaro says "secure connection failed" and chrome/brave on windows says "unable to connect".

I'm sure there's no strange firewall or anything. It opens on few Lucky days and doesn't on a lot. I tried changing networks, but that didn't help as well. It sometimes open on network A and sometimes doesn't, and same with network B, C and D.

I didn't know where to post this question so please just don't close it. Even stackoverflow doesn't open. I have to write this question from my phone.

**Edit:** This is what a lot of sites show.

[image]

Comment: Very Strange. Can you please update what Microsoft Edge/IE says on Windows??

Comment: Explorer says "can't reach the page: check your URL"

Comment: I believe it can be some kind of MTU kind of issue with your network adapter. If you are using ethernet, try using WIFI or vice-versa.

Comment: I don't have an ethernet connection, only wifi

Comment: Then try usb hotspot from phone.

Comment: Doesn't work! :( Tried that

Comment: I think that you are not able to open only https sites. To confirm - first open example.com and then example.com with https.

Comment: duckduckgo opens, bing opens, facebook opens, a lot of sites open on http as well as https. A lot doesn't like google, applause, certain firefox help pages.

Comment: If I was in your place, I would just grab a USB stick, and live boot from some OS and see